# Using variable to get attribute SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, variables, simplexml

I want the value of the PositionX attribute from one specific CollageObjectInfo element and I have a variable that contains the number of the element that I want to select.

What I want to achieve is something like this (naturally this code doesnt work):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("vars.xml");
$number = 140;
$positionx = $xml->CollageObjects->CollageObjectInfo[$number]->attributes()->PositionX;
```

Source of reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CollageInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" BgType="image" BgImagePath="http://localhost:8080/images/dreamboard/backgrounds/pattern2.jpg" BgColor="0" CanvasWidth="960" CanvasHeight="730" AutoSaveTime="50000" SelectedMemberDreamId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
  <CollageObjects>
    <CollageObjectInfo xsi:type="CollageImageInfo" 
                       MemberDreamId="a5d55cc1-8eb2-4e28-9ad9-4b9ea250926d" 
                       PositionX="670" PositionY="50" Rotation="0" 
                       ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" Alpha="1" DropShadow="true"
                       Coords="670,77,887.5,77,887.5,337,670,337" 
                       Type="image" 
                       DreamboardImageId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
                       ImagePath="http://cubicflow.com/dan/dia/images/dream-1.jpg" 
                       Caption="I am flying without taking my shoes off." />
    <CollageObjectInfo xsi:type="CollageImageInfo" 
                       MemberDreamId="2f7a6c1b-6006-4a5d-b9d8-b653ee7ea4ca" PositionX="82" PositionY="323" Rotation="-40" ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" Alpha="1" DropShadow="true" Coords="2,400,219.5,400,219.5,710,2,710" Type="image" DreamboardImageId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ImagePath="http://cubicflow.com/dan/dia/images/dream-2.jpg" Caption="I am continuing to improve physical conditioning." />
    <CollageObjectInfo xsi:type="CollageImageInfo" 
                       MemberDreamId="7230bb7a-58a6-49d3-bfc7-ed7e4486da85" PositionX="150" PositionY="404" Rotation="0" ScaleX="0.46" ScaleY="0.44" Alpha="1" DropShadow="true" Coords="680.75,381.25,880.85,381.25,880.85,736.75,680.75,736.75" Type="text" DreamboardImageId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ImagePath="" Caption="Lorem ipsum dolor yeeeeeeeahhhhssssss sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua." />
  </CollageObjects>
</CollageInfo>
```

Comment: Naturally this code does work: https://eval.in/57664 - so where does that leave your question?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try using XPath.

Something like

```
$attr = $xml->xpath('CollageObjects/CollageObjectInfo['.$number.']/@PositionX');
```

[xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) always returns an array (or FALSE in case of error), so you can do something like

```
$neededAttr = (string)$attr[0];
```

(Of course after you checked for errors)

Here is an [example](http://codepad.org/5YwmL1s9)

---

Another possible solution is this:

```
$children = $x->CollageObjects->children();
echo $children[$number]->attributes()->PositionX;
```

Or if you use PHP >= 5.4

```
echo $x->CollageObjects->children()[$number]->attributes()->PositionX
```

(I dont have php 5.4 installed, so I cant guarantee the code will work, but I see no reason for it not to).

[PHP 5.4 Array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-87)

**A Note:** XPath counts from 1 while PHP counts from 0, take that into account when using your `$number` as index.

Good luck :)

Comment: -1: Code in question does work, no need to answer, wonder why you have not realized. https://eval.in/57664